# Need more help Key Binding

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

Alright, so let me make this very clear, I am an entry level user on Ubuntu, I am still getting very used to it and I require help. See I finally solved how to swap my Super L key on my laptop (which in this case is a chromebook) to Caps Lock. I have done that by going into the terminal and typing

xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Caps_Lock"

Now I am looking for a "for Dummy's" step-by-step instruction on how to make that keybind change permanent so I do not have to input that command everytime I log into ubuntu.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try run on startup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will run `xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Caps_Lock"` command everytime launch Ubuntu (StartUp)

1. Open your startup application by run following command :

   `gnome-session-properties`
2. Select "add" button :
   [image]
3. Fill "command" section with `xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Caps_Lock"` command

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

Chrome has it own shortcut that can you use if you lazy to use mouse. In your case you want go to previous page, forward page, refresh using keyboard.

Refresh --> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd>

Previous Page --> <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

Forward Page --> <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

See also [Chrome Keyboard Shortcut](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/linux/Chrome.html), and feel free to upvote this answer :D

**UPDATE 2**

For disable/enable/assign chrome shortcut you have to install [shortcut manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf). There are plenty tutorial which teach you how to use shortcut manager :

- [ShortCut manager : Assign hotkeys to various browser actions](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/shortcut-manager-assign-hotkeys-to-various-browser-actions-chrome/)
- [How to create custom shortcut in chrome](http://www.howtogeek.com/127162/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-browser-actions-and-extensions-in-google-chrome/)

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. It worked, just another question. See I have a back, forward, and refresh buttons on my laptop and was wondering if I could assign their respective purposes to them. For example whenever I'm using the Chrome browser, I would like to be able to use them to refresh my pages or return to the previous page if I would like. If you could explain to me how to do that in an explanation as simple as the one you gave me for the permanent solution I need earlier, that would be great, thank you so much!

Comment: Do you mean shortcut for refresh, back to previous page, and forward page on chrome ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, and I would like to bind that to the keys I have on my keyboard.

Comment: Set chrome shortcut to permanent ?

Comment: Yeah, well I know that Alt + Left is the shortcut in chrome, but how do assign that shortcut to a single button, in this case, it would be my "F1" button?

Comment: [Chrome Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf) maybe your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a startup application for that. Use the GUI independent way.

1. Open the file `~/.Xmodmap`

   ```
   nano ~/.Xmodmap
   ```
2. Place your mappings, eg.:

   ```
   keycode 133 = Caps_Lock
   ```

   in this file and test it with

   ```
    xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
   ```
3. Then open the file `~/.xinitrc`

   ```
   nano ~/.xinitrc
   ```

   and add this lines

   ```
   if [ -s ~/.Xmodmap ]; then
       xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
   fi
   ```

   If `~/.xinitrc` does not work then use `~/.profile`
4. Log out and log in again.

Comment: Most users like doing everything in the GUI.  Good to know for a server!